# How to add more than one field in row, instead each field in row

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm use `grocery crud` with `codeignier`, but I want to add two image upload fields or more into one form row.

**Usually a way to add fields as in the following figure:**

[image]

**But I want to do like the following figure (all in one row):**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_table('content');
$crud->where('state', 1);
$crud->add_fields('name', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id', 'image', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'text', 'period');
$crud->set_field_upload('image', 'assets/uploads/');
$crud->set_field_upload('image2', 'assets/uploads/');
$crud->set_field_upload('image3', 'assets/uploads/');
$crud->set_field_upload('image4', 'assets/uploads/');
```